# List index out of bounds with a TListView

Tags: c++builder, vcl, tlistview

I'm confused when I try to insert a String into a TListView using `insert(int,String)`.

Here is my code:

```
void __fastcall TFrmNewPeta::showDefaultRute()
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream ifs;
    wisata.savedefaultT4Awal("DefaultDataAwal");
    wisata.savedefaultT4Jarak("DefaultDataJarak");
    wisata.savedefaultT4Tujuan("DefaultDataTujuan");
    ifs.open("DefaultDataAwal"); 
    try{
         if(ifs.is_open())
         {
             for(int indexfile=0;std::getline(ifs,line);++indexfile)
             {
                ListItemnew = ListView1->Items->Add();
                ListItemnew->Caption = String(IntToStr(indexfile+1));
                ListItemnew->SubItems->Insert(indexfile,line.c_str());
                //cbxtest->Items->Insert(indexfile,line.c_str()); //successfull

             }
         }
    }__finally{
        ifs.close();
    }
}
```

With this the compiler says `"List Index out of bounds (1)"`
I've been tried for many times to find the way out but I got the same result.

But this one made me wonder, because when I try to test with ComboBox its works well.

```
cbxtest->Items->Insert(indexfile,line.c_str());
```

If there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
void __fastcall TFrmNewPeta::showDefaultRute()
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream ifs;
    wisata.savedefaultT4Awal("DefaultDataAwal");
    wisata.savedefaultT4Jarak("DefaultDataJarak");
    wisata.savedefaultT4Tujuan("DefaultDataTujuan");
    ifs.open("DefaultDataAwal"); 
    try{
         if(ifs.is_open())
         {
             for(int indexfile=0;std::getline(ifs,line);++indexfile)
             {
                ListItemnew = ListView1->Items->Add();
                ListItemnew->Caption = String(IntToStr(indexfile+1));
                ListItemnew->SubItems->Add(line.c_str());
                //cbxtest->Items->Insert(indexfile,line.c_str()); //successfull

             }
         }
    }__finally{
        ifs.close();
    }
}
```

I hope this help your problems